# How to find the number of open ports in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, port

How to find the number of open ports in linux? I want to see if I am running out of ports. Also, how do I see the limit of my OS?

Comment: What are you doing that you are afraid of running out of ports?

Answer (score 33):

On modern linux, use the ss (socket stats) utility.

```
$ ss -s
Total: 10160 (kernel 10262)
TCP:   10349 (estab 8886, closed 408, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 393/0), ports 3147

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         10262     -         -        
RAW       0         0         0        
UDP       5         5         0        
TCP       9941      9941      0        
INET      9946      9946      0        
FRAG      0         0         0
```

Answer (score 11):

```
netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

will give you the number of open ports, 32 in my case.

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

Will return something like:

> 32768 61000

which means, 61000 - 32768 - $OPENPORTS = AvailablePorts

On my box, thats:

61000-32768-32 = 28200 available port numbers.

Comment: the -a46 didn't work. Any help?

Comment: what distro you running? (that works on ubuntu server 10.04 LTS). Of course, if you don't have ipv6 installed, then just use netstat -a.

Comment: Tested on my CentOS box, seems it hangs if you don't use "-n" to stop name resolution. (netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l)

Comment: Just saw "ss" below, thats awesome, didn't know about it.. much better!  Use the ip_local_port_range to determine what your linux is configured to allow, but that shows you what you are currently using in a much more accessible format!

Answer (score 8):

As others have mentioned, netstat is the tool to use to determine what ports are in use currently.  As to the limits, the number of ports available are a 16bit unsigned integer which gives you the range 0-65535.  The ports that are available for applications to bind to are the reserved privileged/root ports (0-1024) plus whatever is not covered by your ephemeral port range.

You can view your ephemeral ports by running `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`.

To modify that persistently, you would have to add/modify "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range" in the /etc/sysctl.conf file, or interactively with `sysctl -n net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="<start_port> <end_port>"`

Comment: nit picking, but it's not exactly a ipv4 limit. It's a tcp/udp limit. and those run independently of ipv4. (ex. ipv6 doesn't do anything for transport layer)

Comment: Aaah, you are right.  I have removed the IPV4 reference in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer nmap. You can find the state of all ports by issuing nmap -P 1-65535 target. Most distributions should have this package available via their package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
# lsof -n -i -P
```

For completeness sake :)

Answer (score 0):

netstat will allow you to see what ports are open, do "netstat -" to see what fits your needs best.

Comment: `netstat --inet` will help the most.

Comment: I meant -? missing character.

Comment: or read the manpage

Comment: Also include --inet6 (short for both: -4 -6), to get IPv6 sockets and ip-agnostic sockets (the latter being the default on dual stack hosts, see rfc 3493 section 3.7).

Answer (score 0):

'nmap localhost' will give you all your open ports and services running on them.

Comment: not really, it will only scan ports for 127.0.0.1, not for any wan IP

Comment: That will only give listening ports bound to localhost, not all open ports on the system.

Answer (score 0):

netstat -tulnp

The arguments to the netstat  program are listed below:

```
*

  t - Show TCP
*

  u - Show UDP
*

  l - Show only listening processes (netstat can show both listening and all established connections, i.e. as a client too)
*

  n - Do not resolve network IP address names or port numbers
*

  p - Show the process name that is listening on the port
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following command on terminal to check all ports

```
netstat -lntu
```

To see a specific ports status use the following command

```
netstat -an | grep ':6060'
```

replace 6060 with your specific port number.